# Run-time Error Using Formula From Workbook Variable

Tags: vba, excel, formulas

I am using Vlookup formula from another workbook in my code. The other workbook named as a variable `TifuliWB` Workbook but I keep getting an error run time error 1004. I am sure that it's such a small mistake of mine that stops the sub but I can't know what.

```
With MainWB.Worksheets(2)
    LR = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("J2:J" & LR).FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=VLOOKUP(RC[-8]," '"[" & TifuliWB.Worksheets(1) & "]"'"!C1:C71,65,FALSE)"
     .Range("J2:J" & LR).NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
     .Cells.Copy
End With
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try referencing the columns' full external address instead of concatenating in the workbook and worksheet name.

```
.Range("J2:J" & LR).FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=VLOOKUP(RC[-8]," & TifuliWB.Worksheets(1).range("A:BS").address(1, 1, external:=true, referencestyle:=xlr1c1) & ",65,FALSE)"
'alternately in xlA1 style
.Range("J2:J" & LR).Formula = _
    "=VLOOKUP(J2," & TifuliWB.Worksheets(1).range("A:BS").address(1, 1, external:=true) & ",65,FALSE)"
```

Your original should have used the .Name or .FullName property and there were some string concatenation issues.

```
.Range("J2:J" & LR).FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=VLOOKUP(RC[-8], '[" & TifuliWB.fullname & "]" & TifuliWB.Worksheets(1).name & "'!C1:C71,65,FALSE)"
```